# jogl glGetPMvMatrixf() returns identity matrix

Tags: jogl

I can't understand glGetPMvMatrixf() function. Skiming through `PMVMatrix.java` I didn't noticed P and Mv multiplication. Function just returns FloatBuffer slice with identity matrix in front, followed by P, Mv and bunch of zeros. Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
    PMVMatrix pmvMatrix = new PMVMatrix();

    pmvMatrix.glMatrixMode(PMVMatrix.GL_PROJECTION);
    pmvMatrix.gluPerspective(60, ((float) drawable.getWidth()) / drawable.getHeight(), 0.1f, 10);

    pmvMatrix.glMatrixMode(PMVMatrix.GL_MODELVIEW);
    pmvMatrix.glTranslatef(0, 0, -3);

    System.out.println(pmvMatrix.toString());
    System.out.println(
            Arrays.toString(pmvMatrix.glGetPMvMatrixf().array())
    );

    int pmvMatrixUniformLocation = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "pmvMatrix");
    gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(pmvMatrixUniformLocation, 1, false, pmvMatrix.glGetPMvMatrixf());
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JOGL do you use? I remember that a bug in PMVMatrix was fixed several months ago.

Comment: I use 2.1.3. Last version 2.1.4 was released Jan 31. No changes were made to the PMVMatrix.

Comment: I don't see the problem, I've just looked at the documentation: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/PMVMatrix.html#glGetPMvMatrixf() Yes, the matrix is a sliced part, what is wrong with that? http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/PMVMatrix.html#storageDetails

Comment: I've read the documentation too. I can't understand in what situation two matrices within one FloatBuffer could be useful? Let's assume that person who calls `getPMvMatrix()` function whants to get PMv matrix. Instead one have to manually multiply P and Mv. I haven't found function which multiplies two matrices from one FloatBuffer. Instead there is function which multiply matrices from two separate buffers. But why would I bother extracting matrices from the single FloatBuffer if I could do so `FloatUtil.multMatrixf(pmvMatrix.glGetPMatrixf(), pmvMatrix.glGetMvMatrixf(), pmvFloatBuffer);`?

Comment: Actually, by default under Java 1.6, direct NIO buffers were page aligned, it is no longer the case in Java 1.7. Using slicing was a nice solution to save a lot of memory. If you think that this part of the API isn't correctly designed, please fill a bug report. JOGL is an open source community project and we take into account feedbacks.